# How to create a connection pool of connections to the SQL Server Database, ensuring any connections are kept Open

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, asp.net-core-2.2

For my project that is being developed in .NET Core 2.2, i'm trying to implement a Connection Pool of SQL Server Database connections. So that whenever the business entity will need to connect any of the database, it will just pull the connections from Connection pool and use. Also need to keep the connections in the connection pool alive. All the databases are in the Azure.

Can you please guide me or provide me an example, how to implement the connection pool in C# code?
Whether the Connection pool can be implemented using any standard library?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the [`Min Pool Size=`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring) connection string keyword with `System.Data.SqlClient` or `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to indicate in initial number of pooled connections. These physical connections will remain open in the pool when not in use.

Connections are normally acquired on demand and closed automatically when not used for several minutes so this setting is generally used only for specialized cases. See [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).

Comment: how do i handle the scenarios like the number of connections in the connection pool has reached the maximum pool limit? As per my requirement, in such scenario i need to resize the maximum pool limit. But don't know how.

Comment: @MarsRoverII, the pool will grow automatically up to the default limit of 100 connections or `Max Pool Size`. If you are hitting the default max pool size of 100, you likely have other issues where increasing the pool size is not the solution. Reaching the limit may be due to poor connection management (not closing/disposing connections), long-running queries in need of query/index tuning, long-term blocking, or throwing more work at the database server than it can handle.